# Integrability of subrectangle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, continuity

A *rectangle* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a product of $n$ intervals $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2, b_2] \times \dots \times [a_n, b_n]$.

Let $Q = A \times B$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$, such that $A$ is a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $B$ is a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f : Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function; write $f$ in the form $f(x,y)$, where $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.

Define $\int_R f$ over a rectangle $R$ as the standard Riemann integral: the common value of the supremum of the lower sum $L(f,P)$ and the infimum of the upper sum $U(f,P)$ of $f$ over all partitions $P$ of $R$.

**Claim:** If $\int_Q f(x,y)$ exists, then for every $x_0 \in A$, $\int_{y\in B} f(x_0,y)$ must exist too.

I believe I can prove it by using the fact that for a rectangle $R$, $\int_R f$ exists if and only if $f$ is continuous on $R$ except on a subset of measure zero. Clearly if $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)$ in $Q$, then $f$ must be continuous at $(x_0,y)$ in $B$. Also, the set of discontinuities in $B$ must still be of measure zero since we can use the same covering as in $Q$ for each $\epsilon>0$.

But there must be something wrong with my proof, since according to Munkres's *[Analysis on Manifolds](http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/calculus_on_manifolds/Munkres.pdf)*, Corollary 12.3 of Fubini's theorem:

> Let $Q = A \times B$, where $A$ is a rectangle in $R^k$ and $B$ is a rectangle in $R^n$. Let $f : Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. If $\int_Q f$ exists, **and if $\int_{y\in B} f(x, y)$ exists** for each $x \in A$, then
>   $$\int_Q f = \int_{x \in A}\int_{y \in B} f(x,y).$$

The bolded condition seems unnecessary if my proof is correct. So is my claim false?

Comment: Each $B$-slice of $Q$ has measure zero. e.g. a Line segment has zero area (despite having positive length). This makes your claim "the set of discontinuities in $B$ must still be of measure zero" false since you're looking at two different measures.